# ¿Como evitar que los eventos de un control se ejecuten tantas veces como se ingrese a una pagina con el data-dom-cache en true?

Tags: html, jquery, cordova

Tengo una pantalla de captura, la cuál tiene el data-dom-cache activado, en la cuál debo seleccionar un cliente y uno o más productos, para hacerlo debo cambiar al listado de clientes que es una pagina aparte, lo mismo aplica para productos. Esto funciona correctamente,  el problema surge cuando doy clic en un colapcible (este se abre y se cierra varias veces)  o bien activo o desactivo un flipswitch se activa y desactiva tantas veces como se haya salido de la pantalla de captura para seleccionar clientes y productos, en el caso del flipswitch se tiene un evento change asignado en el cuál se agrego un console.log para comprobar lo que se comenta. Este comportamiento solo lo hace una vez, ya que si vuelvo a dar clic en el flipswitch trabaja normal.

Es un proyecto que trabaja en conjunto con cordova para dispositivos Android-iOS

El html tiene la etiqueta:

`<div data-role="page" id="pantallaCaptura " class="type-interior" data-dom-cache="true">`
   `<div class="ui-content" id="popDatosDocumentos" data-role="popup" data-theme="a" data-position-to="origin" data-overlay-theme="a" data-history="false" data-dismissible="false">`
        `<h3 align="center" class="margenPop">Datos documentos</h3>`

```
    <div id="formDatosDocumentos">
       <div>
           <label>Datos documentos:</label>
           <select class="flipSelect" id="opcCambiaEstado" data-role="flipswitch">
               <option value="0">No</option>
               <option value="1">Si</option>
           </select>                                    
       </div>
    `</div>`
```

`</div>`

Los eventos son asignados a través de un archivo js en la creación de la página.
`$(document).on('pagecreate', '#CapturaDetalleCFDis', function(event) {`
    `$("#pantallaCaptura #opcCambiaEstado").on("change", function(event) {`
        `event.preventDefault();`
        `documentos.cambioEstado();`
        `event.stopPropagation();`
        `event.stopImmediatePropagation();`
        `return false;`
    `});`
`});`

Comment: Hola y bienvenido, por favor edita tu pregunta y añade el código que estás utilizando, con los posibles errores que tienes.

Comment: Al regresar, si hago el scroll hacia abajo para capturar otros datos y luego habría el pop y activo el control ya no se reproduce, no sé a qué se deba es como si se acumulara la ejecución de la animación del control